# Disable runtime type check of a Groovy return value

Tags: groovy

```
File file() { // pre-defined signature
    return new Object().with {
        it.metaClass.length = { 99 }
    }
}
assert file().length() == 99 // Cannot cast to class java.io.File :(
```

The test will pass if `File` replaced with `Object`. Can we disable (avoid) that runtime type checking? Generally I'd like to mimic behaviour of a type using the dynamic nature of Groovy. I know about `Proxy`.

Comment: why don't you extend the File.metaClass?